# treewidth of a given graph

Tags: treewidth

Is the *treewidth* of this graph equal to 2?

[image: K4 with C6 with two pendants]

I have tried to prove it through the definition of a tree decomposition.

If its not correct can someone give any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Treewidth is always at least the clique number minus one. Your graph has a $K_4$, so its treewidth is at least 3.

Answer (score 3):

In the survey [Treewidth, partial $k$-trees, and chordal graphs](http://www.ii.uib.no/~pinar/chordal.pdf) by Pinar Heggernes, we have the following lemma, whose proof is given as an exercise.

> **Lemma.** Let $(\{X_i \mid i \in I\}, T = (I, M))$ be a tree decomposition of $G = (V, E)$, and let $K \subseteq V$ be a clique in $G$.  Then there exists an $i \in I$ with $K \subseteq X_i$.

Prove this lemma, and conclude that, as Yuval answered,

> **Corollary.** For every graph $G$, $tw(G) \geq \omega(G) - 1$.

Conclude that the treewidth is at least three.

The treewidth happens to be at most three as well, but that's a different exercise.

Answer (score 2):

The class of graphs of treewidth two is precisely the class of graphs that are $K_4$-minor-free. Because your graph contains a $K_4$-minor, it has treewidth different from two.